# Assigned Roles by Reactions

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have recently been trying to make a Reaction-to-Role bot and have been struggling with some criteria for making it.
I have researched and looked at other peoples' versions of a similar bot on it, yet I have not been able to use it purposefully in my own code.

The goal of the bot is to have multiple options on a message. Here's an example of what it would look like as a message.

```
**What do you drive?**
 - A car
 - A bicycle
❌ - Nothing
```

There would be reactions under the message of each emoji that was specified. Once a user clicked on one of these emojis, it would add a role to them such as "Drives a Bike" or "Rides a Bicycle."

I have managed to go as far as making an `addrole` command (which receives the message the bot will react to, the emoji, and the role it assigns) and stores some info to a JSON file.

The area in which I have been having issues is actually capturing each user that reacts to the specific message, finding out which reaction they sent, and assigning the role assigned to that emoji.

Here is my current code, I'm thank you for any help you may provide :)

addrole.js

```
if(!args[0] || !args[1] || !args[2] || !args[3]) return message.reply("please use the following format: `autorole #channel messageID icon @role`.");
let channel = message.mentions.channels.first();
let messageID = args[1];
let icon = args[2];
let role = message.mentions.roles.first();

if(!channel.fetchMessage(messageID)) return message.reply("could not find the specified message. Please check the channel and message ID again.");
channel.fetchMessage(messageID).then(msg => {
    msg.react(icon);
    info[role.name] = {
        roleID: role.id,
        channelID: channel.id,
        icon: icon,
    };
    fs.writeFile("./configs/info.json", JSON.stringify(info), (err)=>{
        if(err) console.log(err);
    });
});
```

I know that creating an event named `messageReactionAdd` and `messageReactionRemove` are needed, but I'm not sure how to find their variables and match them accordingly.

Additionally, I am not sure how to make it constantly watch one message even after a restart. From some testing, I noticed that `messageReactionAdd` would not continue watching the specified messages reactions after a restart.

I am looking for any guidance/help that anyone may provide, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I've seen on: https://github.com/Sam-DevZ/Discord-RoleReact/blob/master/roleReact.js that there is an event. I've tried this out and it's working.